# Can pass models to Spring, but Thymeleaf still indicates an error

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

My problem is that I can pass models between Thymeleaf and Spring, but Thymeleaf still indicates an error.

Spring code:

```
@GetMapping("{id}/edit")
  String getEdit(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
  postRepository.findById(id).ifPresent(o -> model.addAttribute("post", o));
  return "edit";
}

@PostMapping("{id}/edit")
  String postEdit(@ModelAttribute Post post) {
  postRepository.save(post);
  return "redirect:/";
}
```

Thymeleaf code:

```
<form th:action="|/${post.id}/edit|" th:method="POST" th:object="${post}">
  <input type="text" th:value="*{title}" name="title">
  <input type="text" th:value="*{content}" name="content">
  <input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

Thymeleaf indicates that it can't resolve ${post.id}, *{title} and *{content}. I have stopped and rerun the application more times so I suppose something is amiss in my code, even if it works.

What should I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you don't need path variable in post mapping. You can use post mapping without path variable. So try modifying you controller like

```
@PostMapping("/edit")
  String postEdit(@ModelAttribute Post post) {
  postRepository.save(post);
  return "redirect:/";
}
```

If you write controller like this it will be easy defining path in thymeleaf.

And second error `can't resolve *{title} and *{content}`  is because of invalid keyword. Please try modifying your thymeleaf like

```
<form th:action="@{/edit}" th:method="POST" th:object="${post}">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{title}" name="title">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" name="content">
  <input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

I think this will work as you are expecting.